# Deprecated services list in webMethods

Tags: webmethods

Can any one please provide me list of deprecates services in webMethods for upgrading from 7.x to 9.5.

Thanks,
Vaishnavi

Comment: Perhaps the vendor can?

Comment: You can raise a support Ticket to the Vendor. Am sure they would provide you relevant documentation.

Comment: I would think that the vendor would do this. I would in the future make your questions more with code and what you have or haven't tried rather than just asking a question like this. Although there are times when a simple question can received good remarks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of things you can do:

1) Just import the package into webMethods 9.5 and run a few tests. If your code uses built-in services that aren't available anymore then you'll get an error message saying that the service is not found.

2) Open your services one by one and inspect the code, if your code makes a reference to a service that is no longer available then you'll see it. See screenshot below:

[image]

3) You can right click on the flow service in Package Navigator and select "Find References". See screenshot below:

[image]

In the Search result pane, anything that is bold and has a question mark means that the service is no longer found

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated services after 6.1 version

http://idnxchange.com/forum/built-in-services/996-can-any-1-please-list-out-the-deprecated-services-after-webmethods-61-version.html

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to search for the deprecated services is to browse the individual SAG product release notes and read me files. You can easily download the files from SAG documentation.